# Ruby: "Class is an object and Object is a class"

Tags: ruby

On surface level, this makes sense:

```
(Class.is_a? Object) && (Object.is_a? Class)
```

evaluates to `true`.

However, it seems to introduce a circular dependency: `Class` is a subclass of `Object`, which implies that `Object` must be defined before `Class` can be defined. However, `Object` is an instance of `Class`, which implies that `Class` must be defined before `Object` can be defined.

How can this be?

This is probably somewhat related to asking **how `Class` is an instance of `Class`**:

```
(Class.instance_of? Class)
```

returns `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer as implemented in Ruby MRI:

```
Init_class_hierarchy(void)
{
    rb_cBasicObject = boot_defclass("BasicObject", 0);
    rb_cObject = boot_defclass("Object", rb_cBasicObject);
    rb_cModule = boot_defclass("Module", rb_cObject);
    rb_cClass =  boot_defclass("Class",  rb_cModule);

    rb_const_set(rb_cObject, rb_intern_const("BasicObject"), rb_cBasicObject);
    RBASIC_SET_CLASS(rb_cClass, rb_cClass);
    RBASIC_SET_CLASS(rb_cModule, rb_cClass);
    RBASIC_SET_CLASS(rb_cObject, rb_cClass);
    RBASIC_SET_CLASS(rb_cBasicObject, rb_cClass);
}
```

`Object` is first created as a descendant of `BasicObject` using `boot_defclass`. Later, it has its class set to `Class` using `RBASIC_SET_CLASS`.

The slip-up in your reasoning is here: "`Object` is an instance of `Class`, which implies that `Class` must be defined before `Object` can be defined." There's nothing to stop you from setting `Object`'s class to `Class` after they are both created.